# How to pivot a data frame created from group using pivot

Tags: python, pandas

1. updated from **vendorname** to **companyname**

2.1 after apply option 1 from @mozway, got a new error saying ***ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape***.

2.1.1 update the data frame to reflect the error.(which is changing the score to good for both B and C under the same zip code that produce two ranks 1)

2.1.2 using "first" instead of "dense" solved the error

---updated above

why my index "zip" couldn't be found after Groupby?

I checked the type of my dataframe op (**pandas.core.frame.DataFrame**) which is as same as the example pandas documentation provided.[Pandas example](http://shorturl.at/couK2)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'zip': ["46062","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236"], 
                   'goodbadscore': ["good","good","good","good","good","bad","bad","good","good","good","bad","good","good","good","good","good","bad","good"],
                   'postlcode' : ["46062","11236","11236","11236","11236","46062","11236","46062","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236","11236"],
                   'companyname': ["A","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A"]}
                   )
                   
print(df)
print(type(df))

### count vendor under zip and count good
op = df.groupby(['zip','companyname'], as_index=True).aggregate(
    countinzipcode=('companyname', 'count'),
    good=('goodbadscore', lambda s: s.eq('good').sum())
)

### calculate % on time = on time count / total count
op['ontime%'] = op['good'] / op['countinzipcode'] * 100

### total zip rank and rank within zip
op['rankingbyallzip'] = op['ontime%'].rank(ascending=False, method='dense').astype(int)
op['rankwithinzip'] = op.groupby("zip")["ontime%"].rank("dense", ascending=False)
print(op)
print(type(op))

### keyerror
op.pivot(index = "zip", columns="rankwithinzip", values="company")
```

Comment: Change `as_index=True` to `as_index=False`. Then fix `values` it's "companyname" not "vendorname"

Comment: "zip" is index here....it is not a column and also there is no "vendorname" named column in your op dataframe

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @HenryEcker if I change to False, it gave me an error of ValueError: cannot insert companyname, already exists. why Python is saying that?

Comment: @AnuragDabas got it. because I use as_index = True. should be "companyname"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to affect your `op` dataframe, you can do:

```
op.reset_index().pivot(index = "zip", columns="rankwithinzip", values="companyname")
```

output:

```
rankwithinzip 1.0  2.0  3.0
zip                        
11236           C    B    A
46062           A  NaN  NaN
```

If you don't care about `op`, then use @Henry Ecker solution

I suggest to add `.astype(int)` to make your `rankwithinzip` column `int` type:

```
op['rankwithinzip'] = op.groupby("zip")["ontime%"].rank("dense", ascending=False).astype(int)
```

Thus your final table will be:

```
  zip   1   2   3
11236   C   B   A
46062   A
```

Comment: i used the first option and it gave me "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I have duplicate zip in my sample, why it doesn't work on my project?

Comment: Can you update you question to reflect the duplicate entries?

Comment: sure, I just updated. is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I meant can you provide an example where this fails? The currently provided dataset works fine for me.

Comment: got it. I changed it. you should get an error in which I believe is the two same ranking

Comment: try: `op["rankwithinzip"].unstack('companyname')` (zip and companyname being index in op)

Comment: no worries. I use "first" instead of "dense" within rank. and it solved the error